# How to convert a ZipPath to File?

Tags: java, path, jaxb

In order to work with Jaxb, I need to have a normal `java.io.File` Object. As I do not want to have legacy code in a quite new project, I want to use `java.nio.file.Path` objects.

As gradle resolves dependencies in `jar` files, I need to handle them as `com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath`. Now the thing is, that I am using these files only for codegeneration, and do not necessarily want to unpack them.

Unfortunately, the `ZipPath.toFile()` method throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, so I cannot convert the Path to a File, which is necessary in order to use the `JaxbUnmarshaller`, to validate the correct layout of the file and to convert it into an actual runtime object.

I tried:

- ZipPath.toFile(); resulted in error
- Paths.get(ZipPath.toUri()).toFile(); resulted in error as the result is a ZipPath again

**How can I get a File from a ZipPath without unzipping it?**

I suppose it is possible via the ZipFileSystem, but I dont get it.

Comment: show your code at first, what you did already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not lovely but I recently solved this problem like so:

```
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(zipPath);
final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("PREFIX", "SUFFIX");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile))
{
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
// do something with tempFile
```